# centrar verticalmente texto hipervinculo

Tags: css

Me he creado unos hipervínculos circulares pero no sé cómo centrar el texto verticalmente al círculo. A ver si alguien me echa una mano.

Código HTML para crear e menú

```
<div class="menu">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-1">
                  <a href="P18/indexP18.php"><i>LINK 1</i></a>
                  <a href="Sulfato/indexsulfato.php"><i>LINK 2</i></a>
                  <a href="Ferrico/indexferrico.php"><i>LINK 3</i></a>
                  <a href="HB10/indexHB.php"><i>LINK 4</i></a>
                  <a href="SulfaCID/indexS3.php"><i>LINK 5</i></a>
                  <a href="Camiones/indexCamiones.php"><i>LINK 6</i></a>
                  <a href="Buscador/indexBuscador.php"><i>LINK 7</i></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Style aplicado al hipervínculo.

```
.menu a{
    display:block;        
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #141414;
    opacity: 0.80;
    margin: 20px;
    border: solid 5px #040404;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    text-align: center;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes solucionarlo con `display: flex`. Esta propiedad transforma al elemento en una caja flexible, pudiendo acceder a todas las propiedades que estas tienen. Dos de ellas son `justify-content` y `align-items`, que permiten decidir como quieres que el elemento trate a sus hijos en cuanto a posicionamiento sobre el eje **x** y el eje **y**.

Diciendo que quieres que ambos estén centrados consigues que el texto (que es hijo de la etiqueta `<a>`) quede centrado tanto verticalmente como horizontalmente dentro de su padre.

```css
.menu a {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #141414;
  opacity: 0.80;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid 5px #040404;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-1">
    <a href="P18/indexP18.php"><i>LINK 1</i></a>
    <a href="Sulfato/indexsulfato.php"><i>LINK 2</i></a>
    <a href="Ferrico/indexferrico.php"><i>LINK 3</i></a>
    <a href="HB10/indexHB.php"><i>LINK 4</i></a>
    <a href="SulfaCID/indexS3.php"><i>LINK 5</i></a>
    <a href="Camiones/indexCamiones.php"><i>LINK 6</i></a>
    <a href="Buscador/indexBuscador.php"><i>LINK 7</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```